# QuickBooks SDK cannot add contact to customer

Tags: quickbooks, qbfc

I am getting an error when adding a customer with contacts. The  [CustomerAdd method](https://member.developer.intuit.com/qbsdk-current/Common/newOSR/index.html) has the following lines to add additional contact:

```
IContacts Contacts4965=CustomerAddRq.ContactsList.Append();
Contacts4965.Salutation.SetValue("ab");
//Set field value for FirstName
Contacts4965.FirstName.SetValue("ab");
....
```

When I try to add I get the following error:

```
20130712.211803 E   1508    XercesSAXErrorHandler   Unknown element 'Contacts' -- error at line 24, column 10 in XML data. 
20130712.211803 I   1508    MsgSetHandler   Parser error, finishing.
```

Also, as a side note the method has these two lines for adding "AdditionalContactRefList"

```
IQBBaseRef AdditionalContactRef4966=Contacts4965.AdditionalContactRefList.Append();
AdditionalContactRef4966.ContactName.SetValue("ab");
AdditionalContactRef4966.ContactValue.SetValue("ab");
```

but in my case I do not have ContactName or ContactValue only fullname is available:

```
IQBBaseRef AdditionalContactRef4 = Contacts3.AdditionalContactRefList.Append();
AdditionalContactRef4.FullName.SetValue("ab");
```

So I am guessing that the library and the reference are different versions, but the contact section compiles and generates the error mentioned above. The website refernce has Max SDK Version  12.0 set, and my library has Interop.QBFC12 so it seems to me both are version 12 b so why is there a difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a number of features included in the QuickBooks SDK 12 which have not yet been implemented in QuickBooks. So they appear in the spec and they compile, but they don't work (this was mentioned in the SDK12 release notes, but we've never gotten full details, to my knowledge). Customer contacts is one of these features. See the legacy SDK forum for [a discussion of this issue](https://idnforums.intuit.com/messageview.aspx?catid=7&threadid=18729&highlight_key=y&keyword1=Contact).

Comment: Thanks, will this implementation be coming soon?

Comment: It's been difficult to get information on this. Now that the Intuit forums are read-only, I'm not sure how we're going to get updates. Based on what I've seen, I would advise you not to hold your breath.